# Why can't I alter a button's properties before setContentView is called?

Tags: android

Sorry in advance in case this is a stupid question!

I was playing around with a couple of things in Android, and I was experimenting with changing elements at run time which were specified in the xml file.

```
Button buttonSetup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetup);
buttonSetup.setTextSize(40);
```

However, I noticed that this crashed the application if you make the changes before -

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

What is the reason for this? (Sorry if I'm missing something obvious! I think my brain has gone into hibernation for Winter!)

I had thought it would be best practice to alter elements *before* setContentView, so that if you alter a lot of elements (say half a dozen or so attributes over half a dozen elements) it is not obvious to the user with things changing on screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy answer:

Your xml-Layout is inflated by calling `setContentView`.
Before you haven't inflated it, the Activity doesn't know about the XML.

You can manually inflate a View with this code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nameOfXML, null);
```

and later set the View to this inflated layout with

```
setContentView(myLayout);
```

Comment: Okay... I thought since the buttons were accessed as their own thing (R.layout.buttonSetup) in a way which seemed unrelated to the layout (R.layout.main) they could be edited wholly independently...

Comment: I'm a little confused, sorry :)

Comment: No Problem, it wasn't easy to understand for me too. If you inflate the View than you can change all your stuff like you want and than call setContentView like I showed above